# How to separate each line of function body with semicolon in R

Tags: r, function

In R I have a function "getHbasedPortfolio". The body of the function is as follows:

```
body("getHbasedPortfolio")
{
  className <- name
  pf = list(name = name,
            get = function(x) pf[[x]],
            set = function(x,value) pf[[x]] <- value
            )

  pf$getCash = function(date) {

    data <-data.frame(name=name,value="null")
    return(data)
  }
  pf$setCash = function(cash, date) {

    a <- insertCashTable(pf$name, cash, date)
    return("success")

  }

  pf <- list2env(pf)
  class(pf) <- name
  return(pf)
}
```

I need to separate each lines with commas. So I wrote a code to do that.
The code I used is as follows:

```
body <-"";
 for(i in 1:length(as.character(body("getHbasedPortfolio")))){
      body <- paste(body,as.character(body("getHbasedPortfolio"))[i])
      body <- paste(body,";")
    }
```

Now I am getting the following output.

> body
>   [1] " { ; className <- name ; pf = list(name = name, get = function(x) pf[[x]], set = function(x, value) pf[[x]] <- value) ; pf$getCash = function(date) {\n    data <- data.frame(name = name, value = \"null\")\n    return(data)\n} ; pf$setCash = function(cash, date) {\n    a <- insertCashTable(pf$name, cash, date)\n    return(\"success\")\n} ; pf <- list2env(pf) ; class(pf) <- name ; return(pf) ;"

The problem is that the statements under the pf$setCash and pf$getCash are not separated by commas.
How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Perhaps a lack of imagination on my part, but I cannot think of any reason for doing this. What is your goal?

Comment: it is for storing this function definition in a database and then retrieving those from db for using it in another part of the project. To do that each line of the body should be separated with ;

Comment: Why not use a package? you could also look at [https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Computing-on-the-language](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Computing-on-the-language), but I think if you are asking the questions such as you are, this may go over your head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 dat <- data.frame(capture.output(getHbasedPortfolio))
```

This will save your function line by a line in a data.frame. You can then save it in your data base.

**EDIT**

you can use dat to write line by line.

```
paste(data.frame(capture.output(getHbasedPortfolio))[,1],
      collapse=',') ## I would use another separator here becuase comma is confusing
```

Comment: this function is not helpful for me. Actually i need is the code that separates each line in the function inside a function with ;

Comment: @DinoopNair rellay? You have your function in a data.frame line by line. Each row is a line! So, you can do what you want with it.  see my edit.